# Aspect Based Sentiment Analysis Classifier - techniques on how to return unknown from a classifier?

Tags: decision-tree, sentiment-analysis

I Created an **Aspect Based Sentiment Analysis Classifier**.

i need to return answer with very high certenty ,
so i want to return **unknown**

in case i am not sure about the answer
my model return for each label a percent and all 3 add up to 1
for example

[image]

i try the threshold in the **ROC curve point**  for each label against all 3 and also the **precision** point of each label

[image]

for now i am  just returning the max between all 3 .

attached link to 1172 tagged examples

https://github.com/ntedgi/bert-sentiment/blob/master/decision_maker_weka.csv

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a threshold and after getting the probabilities, check if the percent of probability is below your threshold, mark it as unknown.

Comment: i try the threshold in the ROC curve for each label against all 3 and also the precision point of each label